# React - Objects are not valid as a React child when rendering an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, components, react-props

Edit:

I'm encountering an issue in my React project where I'm trying to render an array of objects using the map function, and I'm getting the following Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I've checked my code, and I believe the structure of my components and the data passed down are correct. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
// App.js: 

const fetchItems = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/items/');
    setItems(data);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching items:', error.message);
    console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(items);
}
fetchItems();
}, []);


const handleOnClick = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const filteredItems = getFilteredItems(items, query);
     setItems(filteredItems);
    };

return (
  <div className='container'>
    <NavigationBar
      handleOnChange={handleOnChange}
      cartitemcount={cartitemcount}
      handleOnClick={handleOnClick}
    />
    <Items items={items} />
  </div>
);







// Items.js: 

function Items({ items }) {
  return (
<ul className="imagegallery">
{items.map(item => (
<div className="item-container" key={item.id}>
<img
className='item-image'
src={item.image}
alt="Item"
/>
<p className='item-name'>{item.product_name}</p>
<button className="item-price">Buy Now{item.price}$</button><p 
className="item-description">{item.description}</p>
</div>
))}
 </ul>
 );
}

export default Items;
```

I've confirmed that the objects in my items array are correctly formatted, and here's an example of what's in my database:

> `[   { "_id": "655b5295f2b8973f21e9a676", "product_name": "Dell XPS 13 Laptop", "price": 1299, "description": "Experience powerful performance in a sleek design with the Dell XPS 13 Laptop. This ultrabook features a virtually borderless InfinityEdge display and delivers reliable computing for on-the-go professionals.", "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81o2W1xNpzL._AC_SX679_.jpg"   },  // ... (other items) ]`

I've already tried restructuring the items prop in the Items component, but I still get the error.
I understand that I cant directly pass arrays or objects but I did destructor it error:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28898:13)
// ... (other error details)

I'm building a search bar for my e-commerce project, and any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You will have at least one place where you output an object into the jsx, maybe its inside this part: `{/* ... (your other JSX) */}`

Comment: You mean this?     <ul className="imagegallery">
      {items.map(item => (
        <div className="item-container" key={item.id}>
          <img
            className='item-image'
            src={item.image}
            alt="Item"
          />
          <p className='item-name'>{item.product_name}</p>
          <button className="item-price">Buy Now {item.price}$</button>
          <p className="item-description">{item.description}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't allow you to display an object/array directly in the ui.

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1. Access each key individually.

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, product_name: 'First', price: 100, description: 'Description 1' },
  { id: 2, product_name: 'Second', price: 200, description: 'Description 2' },
  { id: 3, product_name: 'Third', price: 300, description: 'Description 3' },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(dataItem => (
        <div key={dataItem.id}>
          <div>Name: {dataItem.product_name}</div>
          <div>Price: {dataItem.price}</div>
          <div>Description: {dataItem.description}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice that instead of displaying `dataItem` directly, we are defining which keys of it need to be shown where.

2. Or, you can convert it to a string. **But it does not look good, and probably won't be acceptable in your project.**

```
{data.map(dataItem => (
  <div key={dataItem.id}>
    {JSON.stringify(dataItem)}
  </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: I get the date like this               useEffect(() => {

    const fetchItems = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/items/');
        setItems(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching items:', error.message);
        console.error(error);
      }
      console.log(items);
    }
    fetchItems();
  }, []);    Then I want to put the array of data in the component items.js the way you showed me would be without passing the array to component just doing it locally

Comment: and I didnt directly show it in the UI am using a map function in my items.js btw forget the navigation component, so its like this :<ul className="imagegallery">
    {items.map(item => (
        <div className="item-container" key={item.id}>
          <img
            className='item-image'
            src={item.image}
            alt="Item"
          />
          <p className='item-name'>{item.product_name}</p>
          <button className="item-price">Buy Now {item.price}$</button>
          <p className="item-description">{item.description}</p>
        </div>
     ))}
    </ul>